# Monotonic sequence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Where $n\in\Bbb N$, let $\{u_n\}$ be a monotonic increasing sequence of positive real numbers, let $\{v_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers, with $v_1>1$, and define the sequence $\{w_n\}$ by
>
> $$w_n\sum_{k=1}^nv_k=\sum_{k=1}^nu_kv_k\;.$$
>
> (a) Prove that $\displaystyle u_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^nv_k\ge\sum_{k=1}^nu_kv_k$. Deduce that $\{w_n\}$ is monotonic.
>
> (b) Using results from part (a), prove that if $\lambda/\color{red}{\pi}\notin\Bbb Z$, then
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k\sin^2(\lambda k)}{k+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(\lambda k)}$$
>
> exists.

I am not sure how to do the second part of (a): the deduction

also, I'd like help with part (b)

Answer (score 1):

First I want to note that I believe that there is a typo in your question, and that it should say that $v_1 > 0$, NOT $v_1 >1$.

For part (a), use the fact that $\{v_n\}$ are non-negative, thus their sum $\sum_{k=1}^n v_k$ is non-decreasing and since $v_1 > 0$, this shows then that $$u_{n+1} \ge \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k}{ \sum_{k=1}^n v_k} \implies u_{n+1} - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k}{ \sum_{k=1}^n v_k} \ge 0 \quad (1)$$ and that the fraction in the left hand side is well-defined.

We also have that $$w_{n+1} - w_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}u_k v_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}v_k} - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k} \\ \\ = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}u_k v_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}v_k} - \frac{[\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k] \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} v_k}{[\sum_{k=1}^n v_k] \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} v_k} \\ = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}u_k v_k - [\sum_{k=1}^n u_k v_k] (1 + \frac{v_{n+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k})}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} v_k} \\ = \frac{u_{n+1}v_{n+1} - [\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_kv_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k}]v_{n+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} v_k} \\ = \frac{v_{n+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} v_k} \left[u_{n+1} - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n u_kv_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k}    \right] \ge 0$$ This is greater than or equal to $0$ because of equation $(1)$ which we derived above as well as the fact that all the $v_k$ are non-negative, and thus it follows that $w_n$ is non-decreasing since for every $n$, $w_{n+1} - w_n \ge 0$.

For part (b), set $v_k = \sin^2(\lambda k)$ and $u_k = \frac{k}{k+1}$.

Then the question is asking you to show that $\underset{k \to \infty}{\lim}w_k$ exists.

In part $(a)$ you showed that $w_k$ is non-decreasing, so if you show now that it is bounded, it follows from the monotone convergence theorem that its limit must exist.

Comment: thanks, do you know how i can prove that part b is bounded?

Comment: Use the facts that $\underset{k\to \infty}{\lim} \frac{k}{k+1} < \infty$ and the fact that $0< \sin^2(x) \le 1$ for $x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$. The bound doesn't have to be accurate, it just has to be finite, and you're done.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I'm still not sure how to do it; I haven't done any questions like this before

Comment: @Jake What part of the question specifically are you unsure about?

Comment: the last bit about using those two facts to prove that it is bounded

Comment: @Jake I see your point, I should have written $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+1}$ instead of $\underset{k \to \infty}{\lim} \frac{k}{k+1}$. To be honest, either I didn't know or I forgot how to show that the sequence $w_n$ is bounded. I will have to think about it and get back to you. I apologize for having been misleading -- that wasn't my intention. If nothing else, we clearly have that the limit of $w_n$ exists only if it is bounded, and because it is monotonic, then if it is bounded the limit exists, i.e. we are in a situation where the limit exists if and only if the

Comment: sequence is bounded, so even if I don't get back to you on how it is bounded, if you found out how (for example by posting another question specifically about how the sequence is bounded and therefore has a limit) you would definitely be done.